# Race condition in selenium python bindings?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, cookies

I have run into a problem when running selenium with python bindings. 
I have a rest web service that i would like to call from selenium.firefox web driver with a pre-created session cookie. (the cookie is previously created by a python.requests request, i am just passing it to selenium)

In order to be able to add cookie to a specific domain, i am running a dummy request to that domain first, and then setting the cookie for the second, real request: (if i don't do that, add_cookie throws error)

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://url.com/preheat")
#sleep(10)
driver.add_cookie(cookie_dict=persistedCookie)
driver.get("http://url.com/realrequest")
```

The problem is, when i run the code above, the web framework cannot see any cookies set. If i uncomment the sleep and waiting 10 seconds after the first request and then setting the cookie, everything works as desired.
(I was trying to apply WebDriverWait for an element in the result document of the first request, but experienced the same)

Is it an expected behaviour? If yes, could anyone recommend me a "deterministic" way of doing this?

Thanks,
Marcell

Comment: If i call add_cookie before the first request, i get this error: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: You may only set cookies for the current domain".
So before i could set any cookies, i have to request for a page from the same domain

Comment: Do you use the default conservative webdriver.load.strategy capability, or the unstable one? The latter might cause such issues.

Comment: I am using it with default settings. Not even using a Profile.